# getting the size of an image not with getimagesize

Tags: php

I need to get the width and height of an image. I know that php has getimagesize(), but its execution time seems a little expensive. I need a function such as imagesx, but it seems it only deals with image resources and not image urls. What shall I do?

Comment: If you're working with remote images ("image urls"), the time needed to download that image will dwarf the time needed to parse it and get its size, no matter what function you use.

Comment: really? but because getimagesize seems to fetch lots of more data than x and y; that's I think the reason behind more processing time; added to what you said, page load goes too heavy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `curl` to save the images, but run the `curl` requests in *parallel* - this way it will load much faster (the bottleneck is not the bandwidth, it's the establishing request time, so this will help).  Once you've saved the images to a local directory, *then* run `getimagesize()` on all of them.

Curl: http://us.php.net/curl-multi-init

Comment: but I need to check them, if eligible, then allow them to land in my page. this condition is for the main bold slideshow of the homepage, so it is very critical to behave with smallest chance of error.

Comment: I have already voted you up to reduce negative points. I'm not used to vote people down.

Comment: it's hard to understand the relation between my problem and cURL